# Trying to call a Webservice secured with X.509 Certificate

Tags: c#, web-services, x509

I'm trying to call a webservice that is secured using an X.509 Certificate.
The provider of the webservice has supplied me with a username, and password.
When I browse to the site using Firefox, the browser prompts me for a username, and password.
When I enter the username/password, it brings me to an XMLdocument (not a WSDL).
I can then click on the certificate (to the left of the address bar), and I see that the service provider has verified his own certificate

I have been supplied with a WSDL (as an email attachment), 
and have created the proxy classes using the standard right click add service reference.

When I try to invoke the webservice, I get the following error:
Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority.

I've tried saving the certificate from the website (clicking on Certname left of the address bar --> view cert --> export), and installing it on my machine using the mmc certificate snap-in (am I even going in the right direction here ?? )

but this didn't work either

Here is my code:

```
var factory = new ChannelFactory<ServicePort>("ServiceSoapBinding");
factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "myuser";
factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "mypass";
var client = factory.CreateChannel();
var request = GetRequest();
var response = client.GetDetails(request);
```

I have a VERY basic understanding of certificates, so with this in mind:

1. Do I have to install a client certificate on the client machine (My Dev PC for now).
2. Should the service provider supply me with a specific certificate, and if so, can I get it from his website as detailed above, or does he need to send it to me separately.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Many thanks
Kevin T

Comment: I have similar problem. Did you resolve the problem?